# Hexadecimals to decimal $((0039))

Tags: bash, math

I have a long file with values like this:

```
0030..0039
2194..2199
21A9..21AA
231A..231B
23E9..23F3
23F8..23FA
25AA..25AB
```

I want to convert the hexadecimals to decimal format. I'm [reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13280173/773263) that you can use `$(($HEX))` but with the above file applying to each number I get back:

```
$((0039))
bash: 0039: value too great for base (error token is "0039")
```

What exactly is going wrong here, the message makes me think it knows what I want to do, as opposed to `$(39)` which reads a different error. But it says the number is to big.

Seems like a strange error message, can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number that starts with a zero is assumed to be an octal number.
Octal numbers should have digits in the range 0-7 ( no 8 or 9 ).

The 9 in `0039` is therefore "value too great for base"

This works, though, (assuming the 0039 is an hex number):

```
$ echo $((0x0039))
57
```

If you want the number converted, do:

```
$ number=0039
$ printf 'octal=%o decimal=%d hexadecimal=%x\n' "$((0x$number))"{,,}
octal=71 decimal=57 hexadecimal=39
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk -F'[.][.]' '{printf "%d..%d\n", strtonum("0x"$1), strtonum("0x0"$2)}' file
48..57
8596..8601
8617..8618
8986..8987
9193..9203
9208..9210
9642..9643
```

`-F'[.][.]'` tells awk that our input fields are separated by `..`.

The format `"%d..%d\n"` specifies that we want decimal numbers in the output separated by two periods.

`strtonum` is awk's function for converting a string to a number.  To tell awk that the number is hexadecimal, we put `0x` in front of it as in `"0x"$1` or `"0x"$2`.